# Auto reload div contents with data from separate page with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to reload a page and retrieve data automatically after 10 seconds or preferably less than that. Please i tried so many codes and it didn't work.
Here is what i am using now...

// script //

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
   //     setInterval(function() {
     //       $("#load_msgs").load("load.php");
       // }, 10000);


//var updateInterval = setInterval(function() {
  //$('#load_msgs').load('load.php?p=<?php echo $username; ?>');
//},1000);
//});

   var autoLoad = setInterval(
   function ()
   {
      $('#load_msgs').load('load.php').fadeIn("slow");
   }, 10000);
});
</script>
```

// php / html div id panel

```
<div class = 'container me' id = "load_msgs"> </div>
```

// php load.php file

```
<?php
include('config.php');
include('func.php');


    //$username = $_GET['q'];
    $o = "--DATABASE QUERY--";
 $z = mysql_query($o) or die(mysql_error());
 while ($roow = mysql_fetch_array($z)) {
 $date = $roow['date'];

      echo $roow['message']. " <span class = 'lil'>" . time_elapsed_string($date)."</span> \n <br />";
      }


?>
```

Comment: I think you have a syntax error!

Comment: Check your console and welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: does ur load.php load first time?

Comment: is it possible to load a php form in div?

Comment: instead use an iframe to load ur load.php and check

Comment: @Anuj Yes, you can load the contents of a PHP page, provided of course that the PHP page echos some data

Comment: Are you trying to load the file **every** 10 seconds, or just once **after** 10 seconds? And you should state what exactly is not working now, do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: i am trying to load the chat page every 10 seconds. it's not displaying the data. even though i echo the data from the 'load.php' page

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming from your comments that you can navigate directly to `load.php` and the data is echo'd. If that is the case, here's how I would set it up:

(It's not clear if you trying to load a file every X seconds, or just once after X seconds, Here is an example of both)

#### index.php:

```
<?php
  $username='someUser'
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Load From PHP</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var username = encodeURI(  <?php echo isset($username) ? "'".$username."'" : ''; ?> );

        $(function(){
            var url='load.php?username='+username;   

            // load once after 2 seconds
            setTimeout(function(){ $.get(url, function(response){ $('#load_msgs').html(response);  } ); }, 2000);

            // load every 2 seconds
            setInterval(function(){ $.get(url, function(response){ $('#load_msgs_repeat').append(response+'<br>');  } ); }, 2000);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>    
   <h4>Div loaded once</h4>
   <div id="load_msgs"></div>    
   <br>    
   <h4>Div loaded every 2 seconds</h4>
   <div id="load_msgs_repeat"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

#### load.php:

```
<?php
$username= isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : null;
echo $username ? 'here is some data loaded from load.php for user: '.$username : 'here is some data loaded from load.php, but no user was provided' ;
?>
```

[Here is a functioning example](http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/load_from_php/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in config.php or func.php. Are you connecting to the database before running your query?

Add these two lines to the start of load.php:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then visit load.php in your browser. You should get some helpful error messages.

Answer (score -1):

```
window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.replace("page.php")},5000);
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.